# Block "finally" in a method that returns a value

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a method, that connects to mail server, gets all the messages and returns these messages in an Array.
So this looks like this (pseudocode):

```
public Message[] getMessages() throws Exception {
  try{
      //Connection to mail server, getting all messages and putting them to an array
      return Message[];
  } finally {
      CloseConnectionToMailServer(); //I don't need it anymore, I just need messages
  }
}
```

I can put "return" instruction to "finally" block, but this disable potential Exception.
If I leave it as it is now, "return" can never be reached.

I think you caught the problem I ran at. How can I get all the messages I need, return an array with these messages and close connection to server in a delicate (in even "best practices") way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't the return statement be reached? If there are no exception, Message[] will be returned just fine.

Comment: Why don't you just do the `return Message[]` call after the `try` finishes?  It'd be a lot more obvious that way, rather than embedding the return in the middle of the method.

Comment: It's *really* not clear what the problem is here. Why would `return` not be reached as it is now? Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you guys, I understood my fault. I was confused with "finally" block in aggregate with "return". So it will work anyway, even if I put "return" after "finally" block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is just fine. Even if you return from a try block finally block will be executed.
And your method must return a value :

```
public Message[] getMessages() throws Exception {

  try{
      //Connection to mail server, getting all messages and putting them to an array
      return Message[];
  } finally {
      CloseConnectionToMailServer(); //I don't need it anymore, I just need messages
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Finally block will be excecuted anyway?
Oh, thanks, I was to close to such solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The 'standard' version (that I've seen) is

```
try {
    doStuff()
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    closeConnections();
}
return stuff;
```

I see no reason that shouldn't work for your code.

As a side note, if your code is a 'returns data' thing, I'd generally think it easier to make it a 'public Message[] getStuff() throws SQLException', then let the calling class handle the errors.

Answer (score -2):

Why not this:

```
public Message[] getMessages() throws Exception {
  Message = null;
  try{
      //Connection to mail server, getting all messages and putting them to an array
      Message = Messages;
  } finally {
      CloseConnectionToMailServer(); //I don't need it anymore, I just need messages
      return Message;
  }
}
```

Comment: Message is a data type not an object!

Comment: Because "return" in finally block will consume an exception if such appears.